# Combine Excel Sheets with Different Number of Columns and Different Column Layout in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I searched and most of the questions I found were sheets that were laid out the same but different column names, or different sheet names (or both).  I didn't find anything where the number of columns and column order are different.

I have two workbooks with a single sheet in each one.  First one is BillTo that looks like:
[image]

The second one is ShipTo that looks like:
[image]

While they are very similar, the ShipTo has an extra column, and BILLTO_CUST on it should go with CUSTOMER_NUMBER on the BillTo file.

Right now I have the two files joined using:

```
Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\ME\OneDrive\Contact Template\Current Contacts"),

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
        Source, 
        "Workbook Objects", 
            each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Folder Path] & "\" & [Name]), null, true)
    ),
#"Expanded Workbook Objects" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Added Custom", 
        "Workbook Objects", 
        {
            "Name", 
            "Data", 
            "Item", 
            "Kind", 
            "Hidden"
        }, {
            "Workbook Objects.Name", 
            "Workbook Objects.Data", 
            "Workbook Objects.Item", 
            "Workbook Objects.Kind", 
            "Workbook Objects.Hidden"
        }
    ),

#"Expanded Workbook Objects.Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Expanded Workbook Objects", 
        "Workbook Objects.Data", 
        {
            "Column1", 
            "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", 
            "Column18", 
            "Column19"
        }, {
            "Workbook Objects.Data.Column1", 
            "Workbook Objects.Data.Column2", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column3", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column4", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column5", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column6", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column7", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column8", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column9", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column10", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column11", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column12", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column13", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column14", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column15", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column16", "Workbook Objects.Data.Column17", 
            "Workbook Objects.Data.Column18", 
            "Workbook Objects.Data.Column19"
        }
    ),

#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(
        #"Expanded Workbook Objects.Data",
        {
            "Extension", 
            "Date accessed", 
            "Date modified", 
            "Date created", 
            "Attributes", 
            "Workbook Objects.Kind", 
            "Workbook Objects.Hidden"
        }
    )
```

But I end up with this:
[image]

1. The header for the ShipTo file is in the middle of the results.
2. The columns are offset
3. The columns don't match (BILLTO_CUST = CUSTOMER_NUMBER)

I think what I need to do (via Power Query) is add a SHIPTO_CUST column to the BillTo file, and then move BILLTO_CUST in the ShipTo file to the first column.  Then promote the rows to headers, but only keep the header from the BillTo file.
So it would look like this:
[image]

Is it possible to do that?

Edit: I can't just edit the file(s) because the files come from an automated export function, and I am trying to create an easily repeatable process.  The formats won't change in the export.

Comment: what do you want the output from your sample to look like? please edit question

Comment: Good call, updated.

Comment: Combining files like you are doing only works if the files in the folder have the same schema. Yours clearly do not. [See also this article from Microsoft.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4) You'd be better off importing them separately, then doing the join on the field you have identified as the one they have in common. What results does that give you?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that it can't be done how I was thinking... However, what I did do (thank you @Dolunaykiz) was to use Power Query to bring the BillTo file in (Data->Get Data->From Worksheet) and get it formatted how I wanted.  Then I used another query to bring the ShipTo file in and get it formatted properly.  Then I went to Data->Get Data->Combine Query->Append and that combined the two tabs into the final results.